# i need sql query for sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have 129 columns in a table and below is the table structure

EX:

```
Document_Date   Document_Number Thru_field  Book_Page
R                R                 X                 NULL
O                O                 O                   O
R                R                 X                 NULL
```

i want to get a data from each column which contains 'R' or 'O'
i cant write a query

```
select * from table 
where column 1 = 'R' or column 1 = 'O' or column 2 = 'R' or column 2 = 'O' ...
```

becz i have 129 columns.

Please help me on this i am strugling to get answer from 2 weeks

Comment: If the table also has a large number of rows, you aren't likely to find a very satisfactory solution performance-wise (because of the number of columns and the 'OR' requirement). If you can remodel the table into an Entity Attribute Value pattern (i.e. normalise out the columns) then the query and indexing would be simpler, and performance would then depend on the selectivity of 'O' and 'R' versus the other possible values (NULL etc). You could create a view on the EAV table to give you the same 128 'fields' above.

Comment: Could you please help me out with the query

Comment: I don't see any other way than writing `where column1 = 'R' or column1 = 'O' or column2 = 'R' or column2 = 'O' ....... ` and so on. There's no "magic" way to tell SQL what you want - you need to spell it out explicitly. This design appears to have major flaws - don't expect that SQL can fix those design flaws for you .....

Comment: So... you have been struggling for 2 weeks on how to not have to write 129 column names? You could have spent 20 minutes on actually writing the names instead and you would have been done 2 weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Server Management Studio to write the query you can drag-drop your columns from the Object Explorer and use Quick Replace to modify your statement.

Write the first part of the query:

```
select *
from YourTable
where
```

Drag the columns node from Object Explorer to the right after the where clause and add one extra comma at the end.

```
select *
from YourTable
where Document_Date, Document_Number, Thru_field, Book_Page,
```

Press `ctrl+f` and use Quick Replace to replace `,` with `in ('R', 'O') or`. Note: there is one space before `in`.

```
select *
from YourTable
where Document_Date in ('R', 'O') or Document_Number in ('R', 'O') or Thru_field in ('R', 'O') or Book_Page in ('R', 'O') or
```

Remove the last `or` and you have your query without typing 129 column names.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to explicitly write all columns you can use dynamic sql:

```
declare 
    @sql nvarchar(max),
    @table_name nvarchar(256)

select @sql = '', @table_name = 'dbo.table_name' -- change to proper table name

SELECT @sql = @sql + 'or' + quotename(name) + 'in(''R'',''O'')' 
FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = object_id(@table_name)

select @sql = 'select * from ' + @table_name + ' where ' + stuff(@sql, 1, 2, '')

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

This solves generation of `where` clause. It fails if any of column is different type than `varchar`/`char`. You can read more about [`sp_executesql` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).

Comment: i ran the query i am getting a bug as Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: @sql, I've changed code, now it generates bit compacted query. You can try this, if it won't work I can't help you, sorry.

Comment: NOTHING WORKD I ASKED MY MANAGER HE SAYS ME TO USE CURSOR. NOW ONLY U GUYS HAVE TO HELP ME

Comment: @sql could you try it once again, I've changed `@sql` type to `nvarchar(max)` - my fault :-/.

Answer (score 0):

This ought to work pretty well:

```
with unpivoted as (
select id, val, col
from
(
select
  id,
  cast([Document_Date] as varchar(max)) as Document_Date, 
  cast([Document_Number] as varchar(max)) as Document_Number, 
  cast([Thru_field] as varchar(max)) as Thru_field, 
  cast([Book_Page] as varchar(max)) as Book_Page
  from Table1
) baseTable
UNPIVOT
(val for col in (
  [Document_Date], [Document_Number], [Thru_field], [Book_Page])) unpivot_table
)
select 
  * 
from
  table1
WHERE id in (
  select distinct
    up.id 
  from 
    unpivoted up
  where
    exists (
      select
        1
      from
        unpivoted up2
      where
        up2.id = up.id and
        up2.val IN ('R', 'O')
    )
)
```

Basically, I use the "unpivot" command to move your huge list of columns into a list of rows.  Then I search through those rows to find the values you need, and lastly, join on them to find the full set of your original data.  In order to do make this easy, you'll probably want to make a view that looks very similar to my "unpivoted" CTE, whereby you can list all of the columns.

Here is the query in its various stages:

- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cc6a8/10 (the results of the unpivot)
- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cc6a8/15 (the ids of the base table that match your criteria)
- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cc6a8/17 (the final query)

BTW - I'm the author of sqlfiddle.com