# sql server 2008 - need a query to execute

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
Id DoctypeCode SubtypeCode  Batch_Type From Document Number Thru Document Number
1   ACC CMP RD         R                     R
2   AFD     RD         O                     O
```

I have 129 column in a table. I want to query a table to find out for each doctypecode and subtypecode how many rows exists with 'o' and 'r'

Comment: possible duplicate of [i need sql query for sql server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256919/i-need-sql-query-for-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you could use the COUNT function of SQL.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as "Number of Subtype o instances" 
FROM tableName 
WHERE DoctypeCode = 'o';
```

This will return a count of how many rows contain Subtype "o".  Swap out DoctypeCode for SubtypeCode and "o" for "r" and you should be all set.

EDIT:

I just re-read the question and I think I mis-read the first time...  but the Count function is still probably your best bet.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as "Number of o for doctype ACC" 
FROM tableName 
WHERE DoctypeCode = 'ACC' AND Batch_Type = 'o';
```

When you say "how many rows exist with 'o' and 'r' ... what columns would those o's and r's be appearing in?

Comment: there are lot of columns which has the record with o and R also there are so many doctypecode and subtypecode in the table where command would not work as i have so many column with o and r information also so many doctypecode and subtypecode

Comment: Id,DoctypeCode,SubtypeCode,Batch_Typ,Fr doc no,Thru doc no 1, ACC, CMP, RD, R, R 2, AFD, RD O O 3, AFD, COR RD R R. this is how my table looks but i have just given an example i have so many columns with o and r. I want a query to see the result for each doctypecode and subtypecode i need all the columns which contains o and r